# Head tags inside body

Tags: php, encoding, zend-framework2

I have weird problem with encoding. It comes only when I add 3rd module to my Zend Framework 2 project.
I have 3 modules: Application, Register, Login
If I put to application.config.php:

```
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'Login', //or Register
),
```

Page looks fine, but when I add 3rd module. All scripts, styles are in body tag while they should be in head + firebug shows empty line right after body tag.

I removed BOM from all files placed in register and login modules.
Any idea what is going on and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After I clear browser cache, everything works like it should.
Sorry for wasting your time.